# Expanding series to obtain desired words using generating functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

I am working on analytic combinatorics by myself. According to theorem, $$W\bigg(z,\frac{az}{1+az},\frac{bz}{1+bz},\frac{cz}{1+cz}\bigg)=\bigg(1-\frac{az}{1+az}-\frac{bz}{1+bz}-\frac{cz}{1+cz}\bigg)^{-1}$$

would give the words such that no two consecutive same element appears in its expansion.

It doesnt works in $$W\bigg(z,\frac{az}{1+az},\frac{bz}{1+bz}\bigg)=\bigg(1-\frac{az}{1+az}-\frac{bz}{1+bz}\bigg)^{-1}= \frac{1+az+bz+abz}{1-abz^2}$$

It produces some unwanted words such as $aab$ when we expand it

MOreover, when we apply the same for $\bigg(1-\frac{az}{1+az}-\frac{bz}{1+bz}-\frac{cz}{1+cz}\bigg)^{-1}$, I obtain $$\frac{1+a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc}{1-(ba+ca+cb+bac+cab)}$$

When I expand it, I got some unwanted words such as $bba,ccb,..,abbac,..$ etc,as well.

Why doesnt it work properly when we expand them ? They should have listed all possible Smirnow words. Can you please help me to understand how thier expansion gives desired words even if they contain some unwanted words.

(You can see theorem [here](https://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf),page $205$)

**ADDENTUM:** @ is it possible to show that $$W(z,a,b)=\frac{1}{(1-(a+b)z)}$$ derives smirnow words algebraically when we put $a/(1+a),b/(1+b)$ in place of a and b above without using  my way. I want to see that it derives smirnow words algebraically. I know that $a/(1+a) = a-a^2+a^3-a^4+...$, and it is valid also for $b$. Moreover, we write them in form of $$\sum_{n \geq0}(\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b})^n$$ , but how those terms cancel each other and gives a,b,ab,ba+...

Comment: The order of the variables is not defined when you expand into a power series. You say you got the unwanted word $bba$, but really, it corresponds to the valid word $bab$. Why did you write $bba$ as opposed to $bab$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest because $b(ba+ca+cb+bac+cab)^1$ gives bba. I write them with their orders, the book doesnt say that you can change their orders

Comment: @MikeEarnest if ı change their order randomly, there would be chaos

Comment: If you stipulate that $bba$ is different than $bab$, you are saying that the variables do not commute. However, the authors never claimed that the equation $W(\frac{a}{1+a},\frac{b}{1+b})=\sum \text{words}$ holds as a noncommutative power series, they only claimed it held for commuting variables. The thing you are trying to do (expanding power series to get the words exactly) works sometimes, but not here.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thank you very much, i havent known this, I always assumed that they hold the order and commuting is not allowed. By the way, is it possible to show that $$W(z,a,b)=\frac{1}{(1-(a+b)z)}$$ derives smirnow words algebraically when we put $a/(1+a),b/(1+b)$ in place of a and b above without using  my way. I want to see that it derives smirnow words algebraically. I know that $a/(1+a) = a-a^2+a^3-a^4+...$, and it is valid also for $b$. Moreover, we write them in form of $$\sum_{n \geq0}(\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b})^n$$ , but how those terms cancel each other and gives a,b,ab,ba+...

Comment: @MikeEarnest please help

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of $z^n$ of the generating function
\begin{align*}
W(z;a,b)=\left(1-\frac{az}{1+az}-\frac{bz}{1+bz}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is not intended to produce the *set* of binary Smirnov words of length $n$, but a way to derive the *number* of these words. The generating function starts with
\begin{align*}
1+(a+b)z+2abz^2+\left(a^2b+ab^2\right)z^3+2a^2b^2z^4+(a^3b^2+a^2b^3)z^5+\cdots
\end{align*}
Evaluating (1) at $a=b=1$ gives
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{W(z;1,1)}&=\left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\\
&\color{blue}{=1+2z+2z^2+2z^3+\cdots=\frac{1+z}{1-z}}
\end{align*}

Note: Here we typically consider generating functions as (formal) power series which form a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space denoted by $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a *commutative* field, we have for instance $(abab+baba)z^4=2a^2b^2z^4$.

The authors P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick refer to section 2.4.16. *The Smirnov Problem* in *[Combinatorial Enumeration](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/combinatorial-enumeration)* by I. P. Goulden and D. M. Jackson, who provide this approach to derive the *number* of Smirnov words.

Comment: By way of additional explanation, it may help the reader to note that a term of the form $k a^i b^j z^n$ in the expanded generating function given in the example above means that there are $k$ Smirnov words consisting of $i$ $a$'s and $j$ $b$'s (where, of necessity, $i+j=n$). (+1)

Comment: sir,thanks for your interest to my question.However, I wanted to see that if $$S(z,\frac{a}{1-a},\frac{b}{1-b},\frac{c}{1-c}=W(z,a,b,c)$$, then when we put $a/(1+a),b/(1+b),c/(1+c)$ in place of a,b,c in W, then they produce smirnow word when they are expanded as multinomial such as $$\sum_{n \geq 0}\bigg((z,\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}+\frac{c}{1+c}\bigg)^n$$ and so $$\sum_{n \geq 0}\bigg((a-a^2+a^3-a^4+..)+(b-b^2+b^3-..)+(c-c^2+c^3-c^4+...)\bigg)^n$$

Comment: I wanted  to see just above that ,in multinomial expansion, all unwanted terms will be canceled, for example negative coefficients or consecutive letters such as $aabc$, because in this expansion $((a-a^2+a^3-a^4+..)+(b-b^2+b^3-..)+(c-c^2+c^3-c^4+...))^n$ the order is important,i.e, it produce $abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba$ when $n=3$. So is there any way using multinomial theorem for seeing that when we make transform $a \rightarrow a/(1+a)$ and the same for others in W, it produce smirnow words. I spend 5 days to find a way, but couldnt manage it.

Comment: It can be perfect if someone helps me , especially for multinoms to see large cases . THanks for your effort

Comment: @awkward: I've added a note. Thanks for the upvote. :-)

Comment: @trudycatlover: I've added a note showing that the underlying field is commutative. We therefore have $abc=acb=bac=bca=cab=cba$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer can you please help me about my last comments. I think you understand what I actually looking for as indicated in addentum part. I want to see how unwanted coefficients and patterns are canceled out in binomail or multinomial expansion. How those negative coefficents cancels and we turn from all possible words to smirnow ones ? Please help me to understand this